# Control-Backslash doesn't work

Tags: vim, vi

I'm currently trying to get the standard cscope bindings working but the key binding control-backslash doesn't seem to work. I've tried to test with a simpler mapping:

```
:map <C-\>g x
```

So pressing `Ctrl+\` g should delete a character but the `Ctrl+\` doesn't do anything. I think somehow my shell might be messing up the character encodind. I am using `TERM=xterm256-color`.

Any thoughts on why this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had `set tm=50` in my `.vimrc` which is too small a timeout for mappings.